# [Paraview]; How to zoom it part of the data in Paraview

Tags: paraview

I'm trying to do a visualization similar to the next one with Paraview:

[image]

Any idea of how doing this little box to visualize just a range of points? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Clip` filter with `Box` as the `Clip Type` property.

Comment: but I want to see both boxes, the one with all the data and the other one with only some data. The way you are telling me I can only see one or the other

Comment: you can display both the original data and the output of the clip, with the eye icon in the Pipeline Browser. You can also apply a `Transform` after the clip to move the second box next to the first